# How to process response as soon as it is available using grequests?

Tags: asynchronous, grequests

```
requests = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
responses = []
count = 1
for response in grequests.map(requests, stream=True):
    response_list.append(response)
    if rs == None:
        print('{}. No Response'.format(count))
    else:
        print('{}. URL: {} Response Status: {}'.format(count, response.url, response.status_code))
    count = count+1
```

I was expecting output as

1. URL: https://www.documentonews.gr/sellers.json Response Status: 404
2. URL: https://www.outbrain.com/sellers.json Response Status: 200
3. No Response
4. ....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.